# How does Eucalyptus's MANAGED-NOVLAN mode works?

Tags: eucalyptus

In MANAGED-NOVLAN mode,public ip(Elastic IP) can map to private ip, how does eucalyptus do it?

As far as I know,the public ip is not writed to the vm but to the Frontend(CLC),**eth0:pub**

for example,and then natted to the vm.what's the benefit of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the iptables rules on the front-end (where the CC responsible for the NC resides) to see how is done. I suggest iptables-save to see all the rules.